# Should use Server-side (Explicit) Flow or Client-Side (Implicit) Authentication for Instagram login?

Tags: android, instagram-api

I'm developing an android application which allows users to login to their Instagram accounts. I noticed there are two authentication flows which are server-side and client-side provided by Instagram API. I'm not sure which one should I use for my application?

Answer (score 1):

As given in the [docs](https://instagram.com/developer/authentication/) itself, they recommend using the Server-side flow.

> The server will redirect the user in one of two ways that you choose:
>
> - Server-side flow (**recommended**): Redirect the user to a URI of your
>   choice. Take the provided code parameter and exchange it for an
>   access_token by POSTing the code to our access_token url.
> - Implicit
>   flow: Instead of handling a code, we include the access_token as a
>   fragment (#) in the URL. This method is less secure, but allows
>   applications without any server component to receive an access_token.

So, I'd suggest that if you already have a server for your app, its better to have a server side authentication else you can go for the Implicit flow itself.